# why gui made with glade not showing persian words properly?

Tags: python, pygtk, glade, persian

I want to show data from sqlite3 db to python gui made with pygtk and glade.

the problem is persian words from glade and sqlite db both are in irregular form.
any idea?
[app GUI (all words are in Persian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYIzB.png)

Comment: Please provide your code, including how you select from and insert to the database and set the UI fields. Please also tag your version of Python

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.I finally solved the problem by uninstalling python27 and all modules, restarting windows and installing them again.